# Create a detached screen, send a command to it

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to do something which is proving suprisingly difficult. I want to create a screen session *without* attaching to it (since this will eventually become a startup script), then send a bash command to the session.

I've tried to simply `echo Hello` in a newly created session. The screen session is created fine but the echo never happens. Given the following example, I would expect to finally attach to a screen which has "Hello" on it's console:

```
screen -mdS "Test" # Create a screen session, do not attach to it
screen -ls # Confirm that the Test screen session exists
screen -S "Test" -X "echo Hello^M" # Send a command through
screen -R # Reconnect - notice the command didn't execute
```

But there's nothing in the session at all - the `echo` was not executed. Any pointers are hugely appreciated?!

Comment: On the second thought, I reckon this question is off topic here and belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct invocation is

`screen -S "Test" -X stuff 'echo Hello\r'`

Comment: Oh, that works great! All these examples saying "stuff" I thought were just the equivalent of "blah" in their samples and didn't take it literally :-} Thanks!

Comment: It's a verb. "Stuff it".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`` screen -S "Test" -X stuff 'echo "Hello"'`echo -ne '\015'` ``

stuff is a screen command: [screen docs for stuff command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Command-Summary.html#Command-Summary)

`` `echo -ne '\015'` `` means pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

I found this solution: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/116743/send-command-to-an-already-running-screen-session)